# My content and my background are divs with absolute positioning - how do I stretch the background div to match the height of the content?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs : one containing a complex background, and one containing the content. They both have the same basic style :

```
#content, #background
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

This works fine, until (for example) the content happens to be longer than the window. In this case, the content overflows from the background (which doesn't stretch to contain it).

How do I get the background to always be at least as tall as the content ? I have tried putting the content div inside the background div, or putting them both in a container - but it didn't change anything.

---

**Edit** - here is a simplified markup that illustrates my problem; note that **this one has the content inside the background div**, as this is more likely to work.

```
<style>

#background
{
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top:0px;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#sky, #background-level-1, #background-level-2, #background-level-3
{
width:100%;
position:absolute;
left:0px;
}

#sky
{
top:0px;
height:100%;
background:#ccf;
z-index:10;
}

#background-level-1
{
bottom:0px;
height:100px;
background:#9c9;
z-index:103;
}
#background-level-2
{
bottom:100px;
height:50px;
background:#696;
z-index:102;
}
#background-level-3
{
bottom:150px;
height:25px;
background:#363;
z-index:101;
}

#content
{
width:400px;
height:1200px;
border:#990 solid 1px;
background:#ffc;
z-index:200;
position:absolute;
margin:64px;
padding:16px;
}

</style>

<div id="background">

    <div id="sky"></div>

    <div id="background-level-1"></div>
    <div id="background-level-2"></div>
    <div id="background-level-3"></div>

    <div id="content">
    I need this element to stretch its parent (the div #background).<br>
    The green divs contain pictures of hills and have a parallax effect applied to them through javascript.
    </div>

</div>
```

---

## **Edit** - alright, here's what worked for me :

- put the content inside the background div
- added `min-height:100%;height:100%;` to the background div
- added `position:relative;` to the content

Thank you to everyone who helped.

Comment: can we see the div structure including their parent nodes?

Comment: They're not inside anything - directly in <body>.

Answer (score 1):

Set `#background` as `position: fixed` that way, it will stick with the scroll.

<s>However, isn't it a better solution to do something like this? :</s>

```
#content {
   position:absolute;
   left:0px;
   top:0px;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   background: <WHATEVER BACKGROUND #background USED TO HAVE>
}
```

OP stated it's not possible.

---

Another thing you could do, is to nest them, like so:

```
<div id=background>

    <div id=content>

    </div>

</div>
```

That way, you only absolute position `#background` and the content inside of `#content` will automatically stretch it by default, because it is normal behavior for nested divs.

Comment: Thanks, but no, since my background is a complex background with several layers and some dynamic scripted voodoo. Also I guess setting it to fixed would work, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for. If all else fails, I guess I'll fall back to that...

Comment: As stated in my question, I have tried putting the content div inside the background div, but this doesn't work; I believe that's due to the content div having a position:absolute (which is necessary for other things) - furthermore, it messes with the other elements in the background pretty badly. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You need to expand your question so that we can take all those parameters into account, we suggest a solution, "no but it messes up a different area in my code", then show it to us, it's very possible you're doing the whole thing wrong and there's a better solution.

Comment: Done; I added the structure I'm using. I'm sorry, I didn't mean to sound demanding or whiny. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little JS action to get this done:

```
<script type='text/javascript'
src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function() {
// get the heights
b = $('#background').height();
c = $('#content').height();

// get maximum heights of all
h = Math.max(b, Math.max(c));

// apply it
$('#background').height(h);
$('#content').height(h);
});
</script>
```